# MUI AUTOCOMPLETE : How to render two result lists based on option properties?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, autocomplete

i'm trying to display results with the MUI Autocomplete component but i need to
separate them in two different list side by side.

I currently have a functionnal searchbar with one list, but i want to separate the results based on a specific property from each option who will refer as their type.

Here's what i have as a beginner :

```
<Autocomplete
        freeSolo={true}
        id="equipment-searchbar"
        onOpen={() => {
            setOpen(true);
        }}
        onClose={() => {
            setOpen(false);
        }}
        clearOnBlur={false}
        isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => option.name === value.name}
        getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title || ''}
        filterOptions={x => x}
        options={options}
        groupBy={(option) => option.type}
        onInputChange={onInputChange}
        open={open}
        onChange={(event: any, option: any) => {
            let searchData = (document.getElementById("equipment-searchbar") as HTMLInputElement).value
            if (option !== null && option.globalSearch !== true) {
                switch (option.type) {
                    case bikeSmooveboxType:
                        redirect("bike/" + option.title)
                        break;
                    case stationTransmiterType:
                        redirect("station/" + option.code)
                        break;
                }
            }
        }}
        loading={loading}
        renderInput={(params) => (
            <TextField
                className="inputRounded"
                variant="outlined"
                label={"Rechercher dans les équipements"}
                {...params}
                InputProps={{
                    ...params.InputProps,
                    endAdornment: (
                        <React.Fragment>
                            <SearchIcon/>
                            {params.InputProps.endAdornment}
                        </React.Fragment>
                    ),
                }}
            />
        )}
    />
```

Any suggestions for solving this problem ?
Thank's a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what you need to do is:

1. use `renderGroup` prop and put your jsx for columns.
2. use `ListboxProps` prop to apply `display:flex` for the results.
3. if needed you can check out `PaperComponent` and `PopperComponent` for further customization.

This is a snippet of what probably you need:

```
  <Autocomplete
    renderGroup={(item) => {
      const { group, children } = item;
      if (group === "type1")
        return (
          <Box
            sx={{ width: "50%" }}
            /*custom props for type 1*/
          >
            {children}
          </Box>
        );
      return (
        <Box
          sx={{ width: "50%" }}
          /*custom props for type 2*/
        >
          {children}
        </Box>
      );
    }}
    ListboxProps={{
      sx: { display: "flex" },
    }}
  />
```